# Why are there two slashes - forward and backward?

Tags: special-characters

I'm totally confused which one to use and when, first thing I do when something goes wrong in code with a slash is replace the one with other so my test cases double with one for `/` and one for `\` .Help me to get the logic behind slashes.

Comment: Now THAT's a good question. Although I don't think it's programming related.

Comment: What language are you using? They have a different meaning depending on the language...

Comment: C++, sometimes web development and sometimes mess with regex.

Comment: Programming is like tennis, they have forehands and backhands, we have forward slashes and back slashes.

Comment: Is there any specific case of their usage that confuses you?

Comment: Maybe their main purpose was to be used in ASCII drawings? :P

Comment: "when something goes wrong in code with a slash is replace the one with other" Get rid of that attitude and look up which one is correct. Or else quit programming.

Comment: @Filburt: How is it nonsense?  Before computers, backslashes were uncommon.

Comment: You've missed the other slashes: Horizontal `-`, Vertical `|` and End-on `.`.

Comment: @star because it was apparently written by Gertrude Stein.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [wikipedia article about the backslash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash):

> Bob Bemer introduced the \ character
>   into ASCII, on September 18, 1961, as
>   the result of character frequency
>   studies. In particular the \ was
>   introduced so that the ALGOL boolean
>   operators "∧" (AND) and "∨" (OR) could
>   be composed in ASCII as "/\" and "/"
>   respectively.[4] Both these operators
>   were included in early versions of the
>   C programming language supplied with
>   Unix V6 , Unix V7 and more currently
>   BSD 2.11.

Comment: As I said in the comment, ASCII drawing it is.

Answer (score 6):

`/` is generally used to denote division as in `10/2` meaning 10 divided by 2. `\` is generally used as an escape character as in `\t` or `\n` representing a tab and a newline character respectively.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing like a "forward slash". There's a "slash" `/` and a "backslash" `\`.

There's a long and IMHO ilarious discussion about that on the [xkcd forum](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=59101)

Answer (score 1):

One More Thing....

The Forward Slash `/` is Used in *nix To Navigate to the Filesystem...

Like ....  `/root/home/vs4vijay`

and The BackSlash `\`is Used In Windows ...

Like .....  `F:\Games\CounterStrike`